# Why should I create virtual environments for python projects?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

All the time that I've worked with python and anaconda, I have never wondered how actually virtual envs are useful except for version controlling. When I looked it up, I found a lot of articles on how to create and use custom envs, but not exactly why they are so awesome. Why is it dangerous to install new libraries into the original installation? Are virtual envs useful for anything other than versioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PROS:

1. You can use any version of python you want for a specific environment without having to worry about collisions.
2. Your main python package directory does not get flooded with unnecessary python packages.
3. You can organize your packages much better and know exactly the packages you need to run.
4. Anyone can run your code on their machine.
5. Your project is easier to deploy.
6. Your application runs faster.
7. Ease of maintenance.

## CONS:

1. storage space?

Comment: "and know exactly the packages you need to run" - this is the biggest practical reason.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense, especially points 3 and 4.